# Could anyone be willing to walk me through this Calculus-ii problem?

Tags: calculus

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRrYK.jpg)
I've tried to simplify the fraction to be (1 + √(ln(x+3)⋅ln(9-x)⁻¹))⁻½ and used the arctan (u⁻¹⋅a) from one of the Basic Integration Formulas, but I got an incorrect answer, I think I've improperly. Could you take a look at this?

Comment: This question belongs to [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com), not StackOverflow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on Math.SE, and/or is too broad/unclear (what wrong answer) for SO anyway.